# Copy specific cell contents into new sheet with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am in need of some help. I am trying to copy contents of cells in one sheet into another sheet in the same project. Below I have VBA code that helps me copy cells to another sheet. My only problem is that each cell contains more content than I need them to.

For instance I have:

"Packets: Sent = 10, Received = 10, Lost = 0 (0% loss)"

All I need from the above is "0" (or whatever percentage it happens to be. )How can I automate this by adding functionality to the below code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim LR As Long, i As Long, cls
cls = Array("A13", "A14", "A15", "A16")
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    LR = WorksheetFunction.Max(6, .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1)
    For i = LBound(cls) To UBound(cls)
        .Cells(LR, i + 1).Value = Me.Range(cls(i)).Value
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: Just to clarify, is all of your data in this format? Or are there other formats that you need to pull numbers out of?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the text is `Me.Range(cls(i)).Value` change the contents of the for loop to

```
percentStr = Me.Range(cls(i)).Value
.Cells(LR, i + 1).Value = Val(Mid$(percentStr, InStr(percentStr, "(") + 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to extract only the percentage value:

```
Sub qwerty()
    Dim s As String
    s = "Packets: Sent = 10, Received = 10, Lost = 0 (0% loss)"
    ary = Split(s, "(")
    bry = Split(ary(1), "%")

    MsgBox bry(0)
End Sub
```